# Shopping Cart Price Rule for Free Shipping does not work in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, admin-panel, free-shipping

This bug popped up when I upgraded to Magento 1.9.3(Community Version)

I have set a Shopping Cart Price Rule to allow free shipping from 59.95 euros (Tax included).

[image: Shopping Cart Price Rule]

This rule works fine in the frontend, when our user wants to order stuff on the site itself.
But when an administrator tries to create an order in the admin panel for a user. The system keeps adding the shipping costs. And does not give the expected free shipping at 59.95 euros. Even when I exceed this amount by a lot.

[image: Front office]

[image: Backoffice]

Edit: Seems like the admin panel doesn't accept coupon codes either....